# terminal freezes after running meteor

Tags: meteor

I am trying to install meteor for the first time on Mac os x 10.7.5. After entering

```
cd ~/directory/to/project
meteor
```

and receiving

```
Running on: http://localhost:3000/
```

in the terminal, it freezes. The button on the default page is dead, and I can't use the terminal window any more. I can't seem to find anything in the Meteor documentation about reinstalling or troubleshooting this particular problem. Has anyone else had this problem and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior is as expected.  Meteor is running, and serving your page.

Check out the javascript console on your browser. (on Chrome in OSX you get there by typing command-option-j, check out your own browser's docs for details).  A message should appear there when you hit the button on the default sample app.

When you want Meteor to stop running, you can hit control-c, which will make Meteor quit serving your page end exit.

If, instead, you want to force Meteor into the background and get your commandline back without exiting, hit control-z.  Your terminal will tell you that meteor is stopped, and give you a "job number" to the left of that.  You can use that job number with the `bg` command to set Meteor running in the background.   When you want it in the foreground again (for example, to control-c out of it) you can use the `fg` command.

Here is an example of how I put meteor into the background:

```
Running on: http://localhost:3000/
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 meteor
gobo:blank naomi$ bg 1
[1]+ meteor &
gobo:blank naomi$
```

Note that these commands and key combinations are part of my shell (in this case, bash), not part of meteor.